# a[href*=#]:not([href=#]) - adding class as additional "not" perameter?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following line of jQuery for selecting anchor elements:

```
a[href*=#]:not([href=#])
```

However, I now have two modules selecting the anchors and interfering with one another.  I need this to say

```
:not([href=#) && (class=fancybox)]
```

but that's not working.  Can anyone tell me how to write this correctly? I want it to ignore dead links **and** anchors that also have a class="fancybox" (which is how the other module works).

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
$("a:not(.fancybox):not([href='#'])")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$('a').not('[href="#"]').not('.fancybox');
```

The above first removes anchors which have `#` as its `href` and then removes anchors which have the class `fancybox`

The same can be done using `$("a:not(.fancybox):not([href='#'])")` but I would advise against using it, as it disallows jQuery to use more faster `querySelector`

Comment: `:not` use query selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a comma separated list with not :

```
$("a:not(.fancybox, [href='#'])")
```

The `.not()` function work the same way.

```
$("a").not(".fancybox, [href='#']")
```

The only difference between those two is the readability. Take what you prefer.

Comment: However, according to the documentation: "*The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not() selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.*"

Comment: I thought `,` will not come under simple selector... so that comment. Deleted it..

Comment: @JDB Both are the same speed, it is only a readability factor. Still, will add it as an option.

Comment: why did the original code not have quotes around either of the hashtags?  is jquery not that strict? (i got it online as part of an open-source project)

Comment: @user3899791 because that is not a character that can mess up with the attibute selector like the bracket, space, hypen and etc.

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon thank you, that makes sense.  I understand now.  One last question - what is the function of the *= operator in the original code?  Normally it functions as x = x*y, but here it takes everything that has a # and...multiplies it by something?  I get what the code does (takes every anchor link but removes dead links) but don't quite understand how that operator accomplishes it.

Comment: @user3899791 here a list of all CSS selector : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp. As you can see, `[href*=#]` is an `attribute contain` selector. It select every node that has an `href` containing the substring `#`.